# Facebook Login Details Authentication

Tags: facebook, authentication

How can I validate the sign in details of a Facebook account programmatically? I mean without having to log in physically to the website.

For example, let's say through an android app I am developing, I have the sign in details but I need to authenticate if the details are right or wrong before proceeding to the next stage on the app.

PS: I know about Facebook Login/Connect, but that is not what I am trying to ask about here.

Comment: Using Facebook Login and manually login is the only way.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; do you mean your app is asking users for their Facebook login credentials? Your app is not allowed to do that.